# Conditional Model Binding with ASP.net MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, model, model-binding

I am using model binding (with a strongly typed partial view) for my validation of a search form.

For a "live" search I require city, date, time and other things, but for a "city" I only require city.

Is there a way to set the required attribute on my model conditionally, based on whether a hidden input "searchtype" is set?

Or is model binding, not going to work in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, there isn't any kind of `RequiredIfAttribute`, but **[MVC FoolProof validation](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/)** has these plus many other useful validation attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the link it looks quite powerful. I have also since found this link - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx which looks a bit better explained. I am a new to ASP.net and fool proof looks a bit daunting to install? Would you still recommend I go with Foolproof? I'm a little out of my depth on this one.

Comment: I'd still recommend FoolProof, it'll save you coding all of those yourself if using MVC 2. To install, simply install the Nuget package http://nuget.org/List/Packages/foolproof